# How to display the values of Vector in the data browser of DolphinDB?

Tags: sql, database

I execute the following code in the GUI of DolphinDB.

```
incomes=table(2016.07.31 - 10..1 as date, rand(100,10) as income);
eventdates = [2016.07.22, 2016.07.25, 2016.07.29];
x = incomes.date.binsrch(eventdates);
incomes.date.cut(x);
```

Then the GUI show the result 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGlFE.png).

But I don't know the meaning of `com.xxdb.data.BasicDateVector@64e2a63c`. Can you tell me how to display the values of Vector simply?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
incomes.date.cut(x)[0]
```

The number in [] is the index of element you want to access.